# python - Send Return print to File.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I print return from functiion CheckTitle() to file .txt? This is code:

```py
class all():
    def __init__(self, driver):
            super().__init__(driver)
            self.full = ()

    def CheckTitle(self, Pu, Not, Name):
        today = str(date.today())
        if self.driver.title == GeneralData.PUBLISHING_PAGE_TITLE:
            print(Pu + Name + ', DATE: ' + today)
        else:
            print(Not + Name + ', DATE: ' + today)

    def send_path(self):
        with open('E:\PycharmProjects\Test\data\Result.txt', 'w') as f:
            for pat in self.full:
                f.write(pat)
```

Comment: do you want to add the output of `CheckTitle()` to the file or just print it in the terminal? If you want to add it to the file, where do you want to add it, the beginning?

Comment: I fix it, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def CheckTitle(self, Pu, Not, Name):   
    if self.driver.title == GeneralData.PUBLISHING_PAGE_TITLE:
       return(Pu + Name + ', DATE: ' + today)
    else:
        return(Not + Name + ', DATE: ' + today)         

def send_path(self):
    with open('E:\PycharmProjects\Test\data\Result.txt', 'w') as f:
        for pat in self.full:
            f.write(pat)
            f.write(CheckTitle('Pu -data','Not -Data','Frank'))
```

You need to have a `return` statement in the function.

Comment: I fix it  buy another way, Thank you. Now I need to Create 2 direction but: saveresult = open("E:\PycharmProjects\Test\Resources\Result.txt", "a") , open("E:\PycharmProjects\Test\Resources\Re.txt", "a") , But Iget this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'